# I don't know why my JOptionPane isn't displaying here

Tags: user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener, joptionpane

For some reason, the JOptionPane isn't displaying in the ActionListner when I click the forfeit button, here is my class, there are no other classes involved. One I try to use the optionPane in other places, like the constructor, it works, but I need it to display if the "forfeit" button is clicked.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

    public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {
        JButton tttSquare;
        JButton forfeit;

        JLabel whosTurn;
        JLabel turnImage;

        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();

        boolean turn = true;
        String redOrBlack = "draw";

        public GUI()
        {
            Container contentPane = getContentPane();
            setSize(750, 450);
            setTitle("TicTacToe");
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            contentPane.setLayout(null);
            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

            int xCord = 0;
            int yCord = 0;
            // build tic tac toe board
            for(int rowCount = 0; rowCount < 3; rowCount++)
            {
                xCord = 0;
                for(int squareCount = 0; squareCount < 3; squareCount++)
                {
                    tttSquare = new JButton();
                    tttSquare.setBackground(Color.white);
                    tttSquare.addActionListener(this);
                    contentPane.add(tttSquare);
                    tttSquare.setBounds(xCord + 60, yCord + 55, 100, 100);
                    xCord += 105;
                }
                yCord += 105;
            }
            whosTurn = new JLabel("X's TURN");
            contentPane.add(whosTurn);
            whosTurn.setLocation(525, 225);
            whosTurn.setSize(100, 200);

            forfeit = new JButton();
            contentPane.add(forfeit);
            forfeit.setText("Forfeit?");
            forfeit.setLocation(500 ,165);
            forfeit.setSize(100, 100);
            forfeit.setBackground(Color.red);       // edit in action listener                                                                           
        }

        //main method
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            GUI g = new GUI();
        } 

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            JButton clicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
            if(clicked == forfeit)
            {   
                optionPane.showMessageDialog("Winner!");
            }
            else if(turn)
            {
                clicked.setBackground(Color.red);
                forfeit.setBackground(Color.black);
                redOrBlack = "black";
                turn = false;
            }
            else
            {
                clicked.setBackground(Color.black);
                forfeit.setBackground(Color.red);
                redOrBlack = "red";
                turn = true;
            }  
        }

    }
```

Comment: Note: I tried changing the JOptionPane call to a System.exit(0) and that didn't work either, could be that the button itself isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution! After reviewing my other projects in which I used JButtons, I found that I forgot to use JButton.addActionListener(this);

Hope this can still be a reference for somebody with the problem!